# Query a JSON with integers as keys in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I have data objects that are in the format

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "2": 17
    }
  ],
  "3": 126
}
```

and stored in PostgreSql database in a column with the type `json`.
How can I query these, I've tried:

```
json_each(sc.data::json)
```

returns `ERROR:  cannot deconstruct a scalar`

If I try

```
sc.data::json->'1'
```

it returns `null`.

Ideally, I would like to get some fields from the "1" array.

[image]

Comment: Something is wrong with your data. You're not storing a JSON object, you're storing a JSON string (whose contents look like JSON). How did you insert that data?

Comment: If it is a string and not a JSON, can I simply call 'to_json' on it?

Comment: No. Fix the process that inserted the problematic data in the first place. And it *is* json (but with a string of json inside it), so `to_json` will do nothing.

Comment: Great, found it. I will fix the import, but in the meantime, this is a quick fix
'(data #>> '{}')::json'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the effort from [@SelVazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4286884/selvazi) and [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), I have realized that my data was wrong. It was a common escaped string instead of a JSON object.

The query to fix it is

```
UPDATE my_table SET data = (data #>> '{}')::json
```

After doing this all of the queries start working as expected, f.x.

```
SELECT data->'1' from my_table
```

Comment: Glad to hear :) +1 for sharing the solution

Answer (score 1):

The error means that in your data column there maybe one or more `Simple scalar/primitive value` they can be numbers, quoted strings, true, false, or null.

I have reproduced your error :

```
create table mytable (
  data json
);

insert into mytable values ('{
  "1": [
    {
      "2": 17
    }
  ],
  "3": 126
}');

select key, value
from mytable, json_each(data)
```

Result OK :

```
key value
1   [{"2": 17}]
3   126
```

But when add one scalar value not null I got error

> ERROR:  cannot deconstruct a scalar

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7lEzGVGD)

Comment: If I copy the value, it is a valid JSON, but as mentioned above it might be stored as a string rather than a JSON object.
I tried 'to_json' and direct cast with '::json' but nothing worked. 
That is the reason I posted the screenshot of the actual data.

Comment: `::json` should be fine .. check this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/r97TzvMo, As I said `ERROR: cannot deconstruct a scalar` means you have some invalid objects